# Java: Returning an array from a method

Tags: java

I have a method `createCountry()` and a method `printAllCountries`, which iterates through all countries and prints each of them if they're not `null`. The problem I have, is that I was only able to print out the name of one country by writing `return countries[0]`. However, I'd like to print all countries. Can someone therefore tell me what I need to change/consider?

```
...
public Country createCountry() {

    Country[] countries = new Country[5];
    Country Sweden = new Country ("Sweden", 498000000000l,10000000);
    Country Brazil = new Country("Brazil", 1798000000000l, 208000000);
    Country Germany = new Country("Germany", 38100000000000l, 826700000);
    Country France = new Country("France", 24650000000000l, 66900000);
    Country Italy = new Country("Italy", 18500000000000l, 60600000);

    countries[0] = Sweden;
    countries[1] = Brazil;
    countries[2] = Germany;
    countries[3] = France;
    countries[4] = Italy;

    return countries; // countries[0] etc. would work..

}   

public void printAllCountries() {

    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
        if (countries[i] != null ){
            System.out.println(countries[i].getName());
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: `public Country createCountry()` -> `public Country[] createCountry()`?

Answer (score 3):

The moment you define your method, you decide what you return

So by saying `public Country createCountry()` you basically say I'll return a `Country` object.

To change that, you need to say something like `public Country[] createCountry()`

Comment: Is there any other possibility? Because later I have this: Country newCountry = createCountry();
    this.countries[registeredCountries] = newCountry;
    this.registeredCountries = this.registeredCountries + 1;
    
    break;

Comment: Well, your methods should do what their name indicates, and nothing more. If the method name is: `createCountry`, it should only create a country (and return it). What you want is to have another method named `getAllCountries`, that will return the array of countries.

Comment: That's true, but it's in another method and it's making a conflict. I have a method called run(), and this part: this.countries[registeredCountries] = newCountry; won't work when I write public Country[] in my first method..

Comment: I understand, but the right thing to do right now is to redesign your class, because currently sounds like you have a mess in there.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the method return type to Country []. So  :
`public Country[] createCountry()`